# Пространство имен в XML

Tags: xml, namespace, xsd

Что делают и для чего необходимы *targetNamespace* и *elementFormDefault* c *attributeFormDefault*?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/students"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.com/students"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <element name="students">
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробую объяснить

*targetNamespace* - задает целевое пространство имен для данной схемы

*elementFormDefault* - задает значение, должны ли элементы xml документа, для которого определена xsd-схема, принадлежать пространству имен, указанному в атрибуте *targetNamespace*. Принимает два значения:

- qualified - все элементы должны принадлежать целевому пространству имен
- unqualified - все элементы схемы не принадлежать целевому пространство
  имен(значение по умолчанию). Для каждого элемента нужно явно указать принадлежность пространству имен, если необходимо.

Рассмотрим ваш пример xsd схемы(будет считать, что элемент *students* имеет тип *type=string*).

Вы указали, для атрибута *elementFormDefault* значение *qualified*, это означает, что элемент *students* должен принадлежать пространству имен, указанному в атрибуте *targetNamespace*.

Для этого определения схемы будет валиден следующий xml-документ

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <ex:students xmlns:ex="http://www.example.com/students">sdsd</ex:students>
```

Элемент *students* находится в пространство имен, указанном в описании xsd-схемы в атрибуте *targetNamespace*.

Если мы попытаемся указать элемент *students*, не поместив его в целевое пространство имен

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<students>sdsd</students>
```

то получим ошибку, что элемент *students* не найден.

*attributeFormDefault* - его роль такая же, что и у атрибута *elementFormDefault*, но только не для элементов схемы, а для атрибутов(должны ли атрибуты принадлежать целевому пространству имен). Принимает те же самые значения.

Надеюсь, я смог вам пояснить, для чего это нужно.

Comment: А URI вы сами придумываете для целевого пространства имен? И если да, то есть какие-то общепринятые URI, которые следует объявлять при создании своих пространств. И в чем разница пространства имен 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' от 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'

Comment: Да, придумываю сам, его и нужно придумывать, чтобы у каждого свой был, чтобы не было коллизий имен. На счет общепринятых имен - это обычно любой URL(думаю что чаще всего URL со схемой http). я обычно использую такой `http://(имя организации)/(дополнительный тематический путь)/`

Comment: На счет разницы пространств имен, 

w3.org/2001/XMLSchema - это главное пространство имен, где объявлены основные элементы схемы(**schema, element, complextType...**)

w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance- это пространство имен расширение, в нем содержится определение элементов схемы(**type, nil...**), связанных с возможностью наложения ограничений на элементы, описывающих  схемой . Полный список элементов из этого пространства имен можете посмотреть здесь [пункт 2.7](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#Instance_Document_Constructions).

Comment: Спасибо большое, все доступно и понятно.